# JPA @JoinColumn one to many bi-directional relationship with a composite key as FK

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, one-to-many

I have been scratching my head over this for weeks now and I have no idea how to work my way around it.

I have two tables:

- Author (author_code, author_number, author_name)  author_code and author_number are primary keys
- Title (author_code, title_code, sequence, title_desc) title_code and sequence are primary keys

Code:

```
        @Entity
        @IdClass(AuthorPK.class)
        @Table(name="Author")
        public class Author implements Serializable {

            @Id
            @Column(name="author_code")
            private long authorCode;

            @Id
            @Column(name="author_number")
            private String authorNumber;

            @Column(name="author_name")
            private String authorName;

            //bi-directional many-to-one association to Title
            @OneToMany(mappedBy="author")
            private List<Title> titles;

            //getter setters
        }

        public class AuthorPK implements Serializable {

                private long authorCode;

                private String authorNumber;

                //getter equals() hashCode()
        }



    @Entity
    @IdClass(TitlePK.class)
    @Table(name="Title")
    public class Title implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @Column(name="title_code")
        private long titleCode;

        @Id
        @Column(name="sequence")
        private long sequence;

        @Column(name="title_desc")
        private String titleDesc;

        //bi-directional many-to-one association to Author
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name="author_code", referencedColumnName="author_code"),
            @JoinColumn(name="author_number", referencedColumnName="author_number")
        })
        private Author author;

    //getters setters
    }

public class TitlePK implements Serializable {

    private long titleCode;

    private long sequence;

//getter equals() hashcode()
}
```

I need to link the two entities via author_code but JPA requires me to include both IDs in the @JoinColumn... it's throwing errors on my application since the source table doesn't have the other column. Is there another way for me to join these entities?

Comment: That is the disadvantage of composite key..

Comment: Just to note: I cannot change the table structure for this because it's part of a widely used legacy system

Comment: So what is the equivalent of author_number in Title entity?

Comment: Ohk...was just about to say so...

Comment: @MaciejKowalski there's no equivalent for the author_number in the Title entity.I can't create a new oneto correspond to it because the table is being used by other applications

Comment: Can you create a join table?

Comment: Another way is create a view and call it directly..It wont affect your database and you can achieve your result

Comment: Did you finally find a solution or is not possible.??  I have a similar schema and I would like to know if I can do it using JPA